# Exterior algebra of free modules over Hopf algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, modules, hopf-algebras, exterior-algebra

Let $H$ be a commutative, cocommutative Hopf algebra over a field $\mathbb{K}$, and $M$ a free Hopf module over $H$. Is the exterior algebra $\Lambda^k_\mathbb{K} M$ with the diagonal $H$-action
$$h \cdot (m_1 \wedge \dots \wedge m_k) 
:= 
\sum (h_{(1)} \cdot m_1) 
\wedge \dots \wedge 
(h_{(k)} \cdot m_k)$$
(in Sweedler notation) a free module?

---

The reason I'm asking is because a specific version of this result is used in Theorem 1 of a paper by Guillemin & Shnider. In their setting, $H = U(A) = S(A)$ is the universal enveloping algebra of an abelian Lie subalgebra $A$ of some Lie algebra $L$, and $M = L^*$ is the continuous dual of $L$. They assume freeness of $L^*$ over $H$, and follow that $\Lambda^k_{\mathbb{K}} L^*$ is free, too.

But this is not obvious to me. If the exterior product was taken over $H$, then this would be [standard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297856/proving-that-the-exterior-algebra-of-a-free-module-is-free-via-universal-propert) from general module theory over commutative rings, but that's not what we have. I imagine the Hopf-algebraic formulation at least makes for a natural question.

*Guillemin, Victor; Shnider, Steven*, [**Some stable results on the cohomology of the classical infinite- dimensional Lie algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1996504), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 179, 275-280 (1973). [ZBL0296.17011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0296.17011).

Comment: I'm confused by your comment, any free $H$-module is automatically, canonically a Hopf module and in fact the fundamental theorem tells you any Hopf module arise this way. In particular, it would be enough to show $\Lambda M$ is an Hopf module. On a similar note, $H^{\otimes n}$ with the diagonal action is in fact free, more precisely isomorphic to the module with action given by acting only on the first tensor factor (probably you already knew that).

Comment: Good point, I did not connect the dots there. I'm changing the post.

Comment: First of all, you need $k>0$. Write $M$ as a direct sum $\bigoplus_{i \in I} H$ of $H$-modules, where $I$ is some totally ordered set. Then, $\Lambda_{\mathbb K}^k M = \bigoplus_{i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k} H \otimes H \otimes \cdots \otimes H$. So the question is whether $H \otimes H \otimes \cdots \otimes H$ is free as a $H$-module. I suspect this is true in characteristic $0$ at least, for some stupid reasons like the $k$-th Adams operation being an isomorphism (but it's not quite that simple, since the tensoring is over $\mathbb K$).

Comment: Ah, you don't need the Adams operation; all you need is the fact that $H \otimes H \cong H^{\dim H}$ as $H$-modules (where $\dim H$ is the dimension of $H$ as a $\mathbb K$-vector space). This is a known fact (see, e.g., Proposition 7.2.2 in S. Dăscălescu, C. Năstăsescu, S. Raianu, *Hopf algebras. An introduction*, Monographs and Textbooks in Pure and Applied Mathematics 235. Marcel Dekker, Inc., New York, 2001. So the answer is always "yes" (for $k>0$).